# Laplace-Stieltjes Transforms and distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, queueing, transform

I was going through a paper, I came across below relation,

\begin{equation}
  T=\begin{cases}
    C, & \text{with probability  $P(H<C)$}\\
    0, & \text{with probability  $P(H>C)$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Where $H\sim exp(\gamma)$ ,C(Completion time) is sum of exponential and Gamma RV.

below resultant equation is written in LST (Laplace-Stieltjes Transforms) using above,

$L_{T}(s)=L_{C}(s).P(H<C)+1.P(H>C)$.

where $L_{T}(s)$ is LST of RV $T$ & $L_{C}(s)$ is LST of RV $C$

Could anyone help how the author has arrived at the above LST resultant equation?

If we can write above, how to write for below,

\begin{equation}
  C=\begin{cases}
    S, & \text{$S< T-A$}\\
    0, & \text{$S \geq T-A$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Where $S\sim exp(\mu)$, $A\sim exp(\lambda)$, $T\sim exp(\mu)$

If you give any references, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Can you reference that paper?

Comment: "QoE Enhanced Mobile Data Offloading With Balking", IEEE communication letters